# Re-enter text to a string

Tags: c++, string, goto

Here's my source code for a text based chatting app.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    time_t mytime;
    mytime = time(NULL);
    char ques[100],ch;
    cout<<setw(75)<<"Welcome To Talk Back\n\n";
    start:
    cout<<"So, What do you have in mind ? ";
    gets(ques);
                for(int i=0;ques[i]!=0;i++) //Convert string to uppercase
                    ques[i]=toupper(ques[i]);

    //puts(ques);
    for (int i =0;ques[i]!=0;i++)
    {
        if((ques[i]=='T')&&(ques[i+1]=='I')&&(ques[i+2]=='M')&&(ques[i+3]=='E'))
            cout<<"\n\nThe Time and Date as of now is  : "<<ctime(&mytime);
    }

    puts(ques);
    cout<<"Anything Else ? Y/N ";
    cin>>ch;
    if(ch=='Y'||ch=='y')
        goto start;
    else
        exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**The Problem :** 
When i try to ask a new question from thye user via using the goto statement to restart the code, here's what happens : http://prntscr.com/8c5yif

I can't enter a new question.
What should I do ?

Thanks

Comment: I would use a loop and not use `goto`

Comment: Try flushing stdin after you read ques (fflush(stdin) since you use C functions), maybe some characters are left in the buffer and are read when you are supposed to give more input

Comment: When you debug your code, what is the value of `ch`?

Comment: Just guessing here, but I'd suggest putting a newline character ("\n") at the end of `"So, What do you have in mind ? "`. e.g., `"So, What do you have in mind ? \n"`

Answer (score 0):

With `std::cin` and `std::cin::clear` it's working.

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/qGPxGC)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <string>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    time_t mytime;
    mytime = time(NULL);
    std::string ques, answer;

    cout << setw(75) << "Welcome To Talk Back\n\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "So, What do you have in mind ? ";
        std::getline (std::cin, ques);
        std::cin.clear();

        //Convert string to uppercase
        for (auto& character : ques)
        {
            character = toupper(character);
        }

        if (ques.find("TIME") != std::string::npos)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nThe Time and Date as of now is  : "<< ctime(&mytime);
        }

        std::cout << ques << std::endl;

        cout<<"Anything Else ? Y/N " << std::endl;
        std::getline (std::cin, answer);
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "Reply: " << answer << std::endl;
    }
    while ("Y" == answer || "y" == answer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flush after `cin>>ch;`

Like this one:

```
cin >> ch;
fflush(stdin);
```

And I recommend you to read this (including links inside):
[How to clear the input buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)